# How to set a boolean in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, boolean

I am trying to set a boolean, but it won't let me set it true. It keeps telling me that `YES` is redefined. I am using the method `#define YES (q1);` where `q1` is the boolean.

Answer (score 8):

```
BOOL yourBool = YES;
```

Comment: i tried this but it keeps saying "Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" when i try to change the variable's value.

Comment: @user457303 take out your `#define` statement.

Comment: I did. To change its value I am doing q1 = FALSE; where q1 is my boolean. It still says "Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: Pay close attention to what people are telling you here. You're making one of two mistakes: either q1 isn't defined like this: "BOOL q1;" like it should be, or you're still using TRUE and FALSE, which are wrong. Only these are valid: declare as "BOOL q1" or "BOOL q1 = YES;" or "BOOL q1 = NO;". Change them later as "q1 = NO;" or "q1 = YES;" or "q1 = n;" where n is something that evaluates as YES or NO.

Comment: I switched it to YES and NO and it is still giving me the same error message.

Comment: Have you writed this : `BOOL *yourBool = YES` ? If yes, delete the `*`

Comment: i did not have a * and it is still giving e the same error message.

Comment: if (q1) {
  q1 = NO;
  q2 = YES;
 }else {
  label.text = @"WRONG";
 }

Comment: Sorry but it's not enough. Edit your question with all the code and the error message.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you doing this?

```
#define YES (q1);
```

its a preprocessor macro to replace all occurences of the word YES with (q1)
if thats what you actually want to do(you probably don't),
then use BOOL yourBool=TRUE;

but its a really bad idea to redefine YES. don't.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `define` you are looking for is:

```
#define q1 YES
```

To verify:

```
NSLog(@"Q1 is set to %@", (q1 ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

if (q1)
{
    // Do something funky
}
```